# dataframe, numbers are coerced to NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c("Product 1","Product 2","Product 3","Product 4")
c <- c("1,004","1,80","3","18")

db <- data.frame(a,b,c)

db$c <- as.numeric(as.character(db$c))
```

Then I get the warning message:

> NAs introduced by coercion

And the values having a comma are replaced with NAs. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out! It is indeed a duplicate. What should I do then?

Answer (score 2):

```
db$c <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",db$c))
```